# Make XML to sortable HTML table using javascript

Tags: javascript, xml, sorttable.js

Can anyone tell me why I cannot seem to sort this table? I downloaded sorttable.js from this site: http://www.kryogenix.org/code/browser/sorttable/#ajaxtables

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 

    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html">
      <title>XML Table Sorting</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/styles.css">
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.tablesorter.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="jssort.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
     <div id="wrapper">
      <h1>Sortable Table of Search Queries</h1>

      <table id="sortableTable" class="sortable" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" ></table>

     </div> 

    <script>
    // load page and display table data
r(function()
{
    alert('DOM Ready!');
    loadXMLDoc();
    sortTheTable();
});
function r(f){/in/.test(document.readyState)?setTimeout('r('+f+')',9):f()}
function loadXMLDoc() 
{
    if (window.ActiveXObject) 
    { 
        var xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLDOM');
        xmlDoc.async = 'false';
        xmlDoc.load('Linux_Sort.xml');
    }
    else 
    {
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() 
        {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) 
            {
              createTable(xmlhttp);
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "Linux_Sort.xml", false);
        xmlhttp.send();

    } // end else
}
function createTable(xml) 
{
  var i;
  var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
  var tableInsert = '<thead><tr><th id="problem_header"><span>Problem Type</span></th><th><span>Task</span></th><th id="page_header"><span>Page No.</span></th><th id="risk_header"><span>Risk</span></th></tr></thead>';
  tableInsert +='<tbody>';
          var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("record");
          for (i = 0; i <x.length; i++) 
          { 
            tableInsert += '<tr><td class="lalign">' +
            x[i].getElementsByTagName("actionplan")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
            '</td><td class="lalign">' +
            x[i].getElementsByTagName("task")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
            "</td><td>" +
            x[i].getElementsByTagName("pageNo")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
            "</td><td class='risk'>" +
            x[i].getElementsByTagName("risk")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
            "</td></tr>";
          }

     tableInsert += '</tbody>';
    document.getElementById("sortableTable").innerHTML = tableInsert;
    // document.getElementByTagName("tbody").innerHTML = tableInsert;
}
function sortTheTable() 
{
    var newTableObject = document.getElementById("sortableTable")
    sorttable.makeSortable(newTableObject);
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the sample XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Linux xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <record>
        <actionplan> OAv </actionplan>
        <task>something here</task>
        <pageNo>6</pageNo>
        <risk>3</risk>
    </record>
    <record>
        <actionplan>Op</actionplan>
        <task>something here</task>
        <pageNo>7</pageNo>
        <risk>3</risk>
    </record>
    <record>
        <actionplan>Op</actionplan>
        <task>something here</task>
        <pageNo>9</pageNo>
        <risk>2</risk>
    </record>
    <record>
        <actionplan>Op</actionplan>
        <task>something here</task>
        <pageNo>10</pageNo>
        <risk>2</risk>
    </record>
    <record>
        <actionplan>Op</actionplan>
        <task>Disal1 root login via SSH</task>
        <pageNo>12</pageNo>
        <risk>1</risk>
    </record>
    <record>
        <actionplan>Op</actionplan>
        <task>Disable send and accept ICMP redirects</task>
        <pageNo>13</pageNo>
        <risk>1</risk>
    </record>
</Linux>
```

I have the table piece working. however, I cannot seem to get it to sort. It is relevant to note that this information is being displayed via local files for use on a tablet browser. So far, it only displays in Firefox.

Comment: Are you aware that by using ActiveX you are limiting your audience to Windows computers and browsers that support ActiveX?

Comment: trigger the **sorttable** after completion of XML loading not immediately on page load.

Comment: @JimGarrison do you have another suggestion? I'm open.

Answer (score 0):

Put the tbody out of the loop:

```
    var tableInsert = '<thead><tr><th id="problem_header"><span>Problem Type</span></th><th><span>Task</span></th><th id="page_header"><span>Page No.</span></th><th id="risk_header"><span>Risk</span></th></tr></thead>';
          tableInsert +='<tbody>';
          var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("record");
          for (i = 0; i <x.length; i++) 
          { 
            tableInsert += '<tr><td class="lalign">' +
            x[i].getElementsByTagName("actionplan")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
            '</td><td class="lalign">' +
            x[i].getElementsByTagName("task")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
            "</td><td>" +
            x[i].getElementsByTagName("pageNo")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
            "</td><td class='risk'>" +
            x[i].getElementsByTagName("risk")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
            "</td></tr>";
          }

     tableInsert += '</tbody>';
```

1. also don't forget double-quote around the id:

   ```
   var newTableObject = document.getElementById("sortableTable")
   ```
2. As the ActiveXObject has no method to check readyState, a messy method is to call sortTable after using a `setTimeout` function

Comment: Still no sorting when I click on the header row. Remember, I am presenting this using local files. This is not being deployed on a web server.

Comment: I fixed the double quote now. Thanks for catching that too. Still not able to click on header and sort though :(

Comment: When you try ActiveXObject, where do you call myfuncion()?

Comment: and how do you make sure that the sorttable is called after xml load?

Comment: I edited the question to incorporate a separate call to sortTheTable. And made sortTheTable a function. Still no luck though.

Comment: It may not work yet because Loading XML via ActiveXObject has no method to check readyState so sortTheTable may be called before completion of xml loading.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113548/discussion-between-ali-sheikhpour-and-user3486667).